# Circleci 2.0 Git Tag Job Execution

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

The [documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#git-tag-job-execution) says that the following will build and deploy for git tag matching `/$v.*/`:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-n-release:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
      - release:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^v.*/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
```

Trying to get this to work on [my project](https://github.com/simbo1905/openshiftbot/blob/v0.0.2/.circleci/config.yaml) builds are only happening on branches and tags name `v0.0.1` and `v0.0.2` were [ignored by circleci](https://circleci.com/gh/simbo1905/openshiftbot).

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

It appears that workflows are being ignored on my project. I see " has no workflows configured" under workflows. I have tried deleting and recreating and that does not work. I have tried copying exactly with no changes a demo [config.yml](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-workflows/blob/ec39e2a3c39675a6867885b378238da19c8a5882/.circleci/config.yml). I have tried deleting my fork and recreating it.

Comment: I would open a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I had named my file `config.yaml` not `config.yml` and it was being ignored. The build job running was Circleci 1.0 with its defaults. Doh!